# MySQL database with multiple user types

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm designing a MySQL database with some tables for a clinic and I need three different user types: admin, medic and patient.

What I did was to create a table called **users** where its columns are precisely the common fields shared by admins, medics and patients (there is of course a primary key called *id_user* which auto increments every time a user is added).

Then I created three tables regarding the specific data for each user type: **admin**, **medic** and **patient** in which I have a field called *id_user* which is a foreign key to *id_user* in the table **users**.

When I tried to establish the foreign key constraint for the three user type tables, phpMyAdmin doesn't allow me to set ON DELETE as "SET NULL" (I think that would make sense because if I delete a user from the **users** table then it should automatically set the fields as NULL in the **medic**, **admin** or **patient** tables, right?) and gives me the error "*relation has not been added*".

**Doubt 1**: What's happening here that I'm not aware of?

**Doubt 2**: Should I forget this way of relating tables and simply add the specific fields for each user type in the **users** table although some users will have some fields set as NULL?

Here is an image illustrating my database:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Cascading Deletes](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) instead of setting fields null, if you delete a user you want them gone if you null out the data you'll just have tables filled with nulls.

Also from what i understand you created 3 tables for each of the permission levels if this is the case you should maybe handle that in code with conditions checking the permissions level